# byte array to double

Tags: objective-c, c

I have a four byte char array and I want to convert it to double. How can I achieve this in C.

Comment: That entirely depends on what your four byte char array represents.  Is it an integer? A fixed-point number? A floating-point number? In what format?

Comment: There's more than one format of floating point number.

Answer (score 2):

`float` and `double` are so closely related in `C` that an explicit conversion is probably not needed.  However, it would be necessary for transmission to another system, or to match a data format specification.  This will do what you ask:

```
union {
    char   c [4];
    float  f;
} x;
double d;

memcpy (x.c, character_source, sizeof x.c);
d = x.f;
```