# How to write and read float data fast, not using string?

Tags: ios

I have many float data which is generated from an image. I want to store it to a file, like XX.dat ( general in C). and I will read it again to do further processing.

I have method to represent float by nsstring and write it in to .txt file. but it is too slow. Is there some function which is same as fwrite( *data , *pfile) and fread(*buf, *pfile) in c? or some new idea?

many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In iOS you can still make use of the standard low-level file (and socket, among other things) API's.  So you can use `fopen()`, `fwrite()`, `fread()`, etc. just as you would in any other C program.

This question has some examples of using the low-level file API on iOS:  [iPhone Unzip code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code)

Another option to consider is writing your floats into something like an `NSMutableData` instance, and then writing that to file.  That will be faster than converting everything to strings (you'll get a binary file instead of a text one), though probably still not as fast as using the low-level API's.  And you'd probably have to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606331/byte-array-to-double) to convert between floats and byte-arrays.

Comment: Many Thanks to aroth! With you Guide, I finish the work, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with lower level access, you could mmap your file, and then access the data directly just as you would any allocated memory.

Comment: I wrote c code to write or read data with lower level access but no idea in object-c. thanks for your tip. I will try aroth's methods.

Comment: Objective-C is a superset of C.  Anything you can do in C, you can do in Objective-C.